# Get "Default Activity not found" when I want to change the starting activity

Tags: java, android-studio

https://github.com/rrsaikat/Scientific-Calculator-Calc-

I am creating a ScientificCalculator by referring to the above Github link, and I want to display the login activity before opening the calculation screen, but the Default Activity not found is displayed. What should I do?

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rrsaikat.calc">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Before I edit↓

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rrsaikat.calc">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: android need android.intent.action.MAIN, you cant remove it.

Comment: Ok, I changed "<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />" to "<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />"
However, It suddenly stopped while implementing it.